# Non ASCII character error python

Tags: python-2.7, non-ascii-characters

I'm a beginner programmer trying to write a python script that will generate random passwords. However, I always get a non-ASCII character error even though I declared the coding #utf-8, as mentioned in another similar question here in Stack Overflow. This is the source code:

```
import string
import random
#coding: utf-8
print "Password generator will create a random customizable password."
print "Choose your options wisely."
number = int(input("How many letters do you want in your password?"))
caps = str(input("Do you want capital letters in your password? Y/N"))
symbols = str(input( "Do you want punctuation, numbers and other symbols in your password? Y/N"))
punctuation = ("!", ".", ":", ";", ",", "?", "'", "@", "£", "$", "«", "»", "~", "^","%", "#", "&", "/", range(0, 11))
lowercase = string.ascii_lowercase
uppercase = string.ascii_uppercase
if caps == "N":
    characters = lowercase
else:
    characters = uppercase + lowercase
if symbols == "Y":
    characters += punctuation
password = random.sample(characters, number)
print "The password is", password "."
```

This is the terminal output

pedro@pedro-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop$ python passwordgenerator.py

File "passwordgenerator.py", line 9
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file passwordgenerator.py on line 9, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

I checked the link but I couldn't understand a thing, maybe because I'm not a native english speaker and since I started programming not long ago.Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: use `raw_input()` on Python 2.7 instead of `input()`. The latter evals its input i.e., it works like `eval(raw_input())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `>>` and `<<` symbols in your punctuations list.

These are not valid. Try to find their unicode code instead

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/bb/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ab/index.htm

**EDIT:
Oh, but wait, this is a password generator, so NO do not even put the double chevrons as part of the punctuations list, as these are not valid in any password.**

```
punctuation = ("!", ".", ":", ";", ",", "?", "'", "@", "$", "~", "^", "%", "#", "&", "/", range(0, 11))
```

Also, why do you add digits to the punctuation tuple?

Why not using string.punctuation and string.digits instead?

Comment: So in the links you gave me it says that « in python source code is u"\u00AB"and » is u"\u00BB". Should I include this inside "" or not?

Comment: I deleted them, but it's still not working. I get the same mistake

Comment: Here is the punctuation variable that I currently have:        punctuation = ("!", ".", ":", ";", ",", "?", "'", "@", "£", "$", "~", "^","%", "#", "&", "/", range(0, 11))

Comment: Try without the Sterling Pound symbol

Comment: I did that and removed the full stop at the end of the last print statement and I get this output in terminal:pedro@pedro-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop$ python passwordgenerator.py
Password generator will create a random customizable password.
Choose your options wisely.
How many letters do you want in your password?9
Do you want capital letters in your password? Y/NY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "passwordgenerator.py", line 7, in <module>
    caps = str(input("Do you want capital letters in your password? Y/N"))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Y' is not defined

Comment: Sorry because it looks kinda messy, but I couldn't put any more characters in that last comment. I think this mistake is an exception or sth. However, I have never written any code that deals with exceptions. It's something like try ..... finally, right?

Comment: Try using raw_input instead of input to see if it works

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot. Btw, why did the shift to raw_input do the trick

Comment: raw_input must be used instead of input, when you want to capture strings or numbers. FYI, Python 3's input is actually raw_input, the old input has been removed from Python 3.

Comment: To answer your question, I have no idea what a digit is, or what string.punctuation and string.digits would do. However, I'll surely search it. Thanks, kind stranger

Comment: @Apero Those characters should be fine, he's specified the file is UTF-8. He just needs to move the coding line to the top of the file.

Comment: True, but as I mentioned, this couldn't be used by a user when he has to type his password, so it's better to use only items from strings.punctuation

Comment: Sorry @agf and  Apero , can't upvote any of your answers, tried to and it says Vote up requires 15 reputation :(

Comment: Forget about that, now I was able to upvote, it's done

Answer (score 5):

The `#coding: utf-8` line needs to be at the top of the file to allow non-ASCII characters.

`£`, `«`, and `»`, are not ASCII.

While you probably don't want non-ascii characters in your password, and they wouldn't be allowed on most sites, there is no reason they couldn't theoretically be permitted.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Mac, there is file .DS_STORE which causes the ascii error while reading contents of your folder.

So do these if you're using mac

- Remove all DS_Store files
- Select Applications > Utilities to launch Terminal.
- Enter the following UNIX command:
- sudo find / -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;
- When prompted for a password enter your Mac OS X Administrator
  password

Comment: While this is a good answer and possible, a more likely cause on a Mac is copying from an editor to a terminal which leads to non-Python friendly leading whitespace.  Simply replacing the leading whitespace will correct the issue.